# Setting up Prometheus / Grafana in Kubernetes for RabbitMQ alerts

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, monitoring, prometheus, grafana

I have setup *Prometheus / Grafana* in Kubernetes using **stable/prometheus-operator** helm chart. I have setup RabbitMQ exporter helm chart as well. I have to setup the alerts for RabbitMQ which is running on k8s. I can't see any target for RabbitMQ in Prometheus. RabbitMQ is not showing up in targets so that I can monitor metrics. It's critical.

Comment: Did you configured your prometheus scrape_configs as mentioned [here](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/tree/master/documentation/examples/kubernetes-rabbitmq)? Additionally take a look at this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@sofienememmi/scrape-your-service-rabbitmq-messages-with-prometheus-kubernetes-b4f711993f19).

Comment: @jt97 yeah I have tried that however RabbitMQ is not showing up in target.

Answer (score 0):

Target in the RabbitMQ exporter can be set by passing the arguments to the helmchart. We have to just set the url and password of RabbitMQ in helmchart using **--set**.